# Открыть файл с помощю другой

Tags: windows, файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть файл base.db
Когда я открывал его показывалось предложение: открыть с помощю другого приложения
Я открыл его с помощю sqlite studio
Теперь я не знаю как сделать по прежднему...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А «по прежднему» это как конкретно?

Comment: это перед тем когда я нажал открыть с помощю и забыл убрать галочку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, вы хотите, чтобы файл открывался по умолчанию с помощью той программы, с помощью которой он открывался по умолчанию раньше.

Вот как можно решить вашу проблему:

1. Нужно щёлкнуть правой клавишей мыши по файлу, выбрать <открыть c помощью<выбрать программу.
2. Поставьте галочку в пункте "Использовать выбранную программу для всех файлов такого типа".
3. Выберите программу, с помощью которой вы хотите открывать этот тип файлов в будущем.

Вот скриншоты:

[image: открыть с помощью...]

[image: выбор программы]